# Ionic: How to stop reloading page content once its completely loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am new to `ionic1 framework` and working on *`sidemenu ionic app`*.      For redirection i am using

`$state.go('app.home', {},{location: "replace", reload: true});`.

when i switch to other tab and return back to previously loaded page it get load all content again.

How to prevent  reloading of page content every time.

Please help me.

Comment: I think when you create new state as like .state('app.settings', {
        url: '/settings',
        cache: false,
        views: {
            'viewContent': {
                templateUrl: 'templates/views/settings.html',
                controller: 'SettingsController'
            }
        }
    })
 ..... You should false cache in app.js route

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply , yes i have false cache in new state but no luck...

Comment: can you edit your question and explain completely here 'How to prevent reloading of page content every time.' so i can help you

Comment: have you tried just do:  $state.go('app.home')

Comment: Yes i have tried $state.go('app.home') but its reload content.

Answer (score 0):

I think , You have to cache false when you create new state in app.js . e.g.

```
.state('app.settings', {
        url: '/settings',
        cache: false,
        views: {
            'viewContent': {
                templateUrl: 'templates/views/settings.html',
                controller: 'SettingsController'
            }
        }
    })
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer but i have already  tried this but no luck... :(

Comment: hey @NupurJain just do cache:true rather than false . Its may be working

Comment: as you told me to false cache i have tried it but now  i am unable to redirect to other pages.

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
$state.transitionTo('app.home');
```

The problem is the `reload: true`

Comment: hey @Grork  i have tried your solution but  `$state.transitionTo` also not working when i swipe back to previously loaded page again it reload all contents.

Answer (score 0):

```
.state('tab.timeline', {
  url: '/timeline',
  cache: true,
  views: {
    'tab-timeline': {
      templateUrl: 'templates/timeline.html',
      controller: 'time'
    }
  }
})
```

This worked for me instantly almost cried tears of joy, just make cache true